# How do I check how many events are happening within 2 seconds? (timer)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, loops, timer

I need to check how many events are detected within 2 seconds.  I have the timer working and I have everything else working...but I ran into a problem: the loop only checks one time, per second and I can't seem to figure out how to fix that.  I need it to check constantly during these two seconds to see how many events there were in total!

Here is what I have:

```
int seconds = 0;
System.out.println("Seconds: " + seconds);
while(seconds < 2)
{
    //Wait 1 second
    try {                                
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}

    seconds++;
    System.out.println("Seconds: " + seconds);

    //This needs to be looping the whole time. 
    //But right now, it's being blocked and only checked once
    if(eventDetected() && seconds <= 2){
        events++;
    } 
}
```

So you can see my problem.  I can't split them up because then the second timer would run, and THEN eventDetected() would be checked.  I need it to check constantly DURING the two second timer...so I basically need both things to happen at once.  Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks for any help ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your design pattern needs work -- I don't know what type event you're looking to detect, but no matter how short your sleep time is, there's a chance you could miss an event using the current pattern.  Here's what I suggest:

Have `eventDetected()` increment your `events` counter.  That way, you won't miss an event.

Then, you just need a way to turn on and off listening (and perhaps resetting the event counter).  If you're sure that in you're current pattern you are really in a different thread that won't block your `eventDetected()` method, you could set a flag to check.  For example:

When you want to start listening:

`listenForEvents = true;`

In eventDetected():

`if (listenForEvents) { events++; }`

When you want to stop listening (for example, after your `Thread.sleep()` call):

```
listenForEvents = false;
```

With multithreading, make sure to watch out for concurrency issues checking and setting the variables, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would tell you what kind of event I have to keep track of but then I'd have to kill you :D

Answered my own question.  Hopefully this will help anyone else out who has a similar problem at some point! I looked up multithreading a bit...

I created a new class EventTimer which implements Runnable, with a public field for seconds:

```
public class EventTimer implements Runnable{
int seconds;
static int timerThreadCount = 0;
Thread t;

public EventTimer() {
    timerThreadCount++;
    this.seconds = 0;
    t = new Thread(this, "Event Timer");
    t.start(); // Start the thread
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(seconds < 2)
    {
        //Wait 1 second
        try {                                
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Waiting interupted.");
        }

        seconds++;
        System.out.println("Seconds: " + seconds);
    }
}

}
```

Then I used an instance of the EventTimer, and used a while loop & if statement to solve my problem.

```
EventTimer t = new EventTimer();
    while(t.seconds < 2){
    if(eventDetected()) events++;
}
```

It was actually quite simple!  I realize that each iteration of my loop of operation (since the entire code piece above is inside an infinite loop) will create a new EventTimer thread and I will eventually run into memory problems however.  How would I close/end a thread after the timer has reached 2 seconds?

Comment: You still have the potential to miss an event -- I strongly suggest incrementing events within eventDetected()

Comment: Ah! thank you! I see what you're saying.  I'll have to change a bunch in my code to implement that. I realize that each iteration of my loop of operation (since the entire code piece above is inside an infinite loop) will create a new EventTimer thread and I will eventually run into memory problems however. How would I close/end a thread after the timer has reached 2 seconds?

Comment: Your Runnable as it is now will end after roughly 2 seconds as it is now, I believe.  Once the run() call finishes, it's done.

Comment: I see you're new to StackOverflow -- it's a common practice to at least upvote, if not accept answers that help you achieve your goal.